# How to display certain column in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a column in my **MS SQL** table(**NumIE**) which is of type integer and when it contains value of -1, it means it is empty. I want to tell this specific column in the `DataGrid` to display empty field when my table data column has value of -1 and display its actual value when different than -1.

Can you show me some example how to format my column to this specific logic?

Comment: Please show us how your DataGrid is defined? Are you for example using auto-generated columns?

Comment: @mm8 yes auto-generated columns. Should I make them myself?

Comment: @VIad: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "NumIE")
    {
        const string CellTemplate = "<DataTemplate xmlns =\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">" +
                    "   <TextBlock>" +
                    "       <TextBlock.Style>" +
                    "           <Style TargetType=\"TextBlock\">" +
                    "               <Setter Property=\"Text\" Value=\"{Binding NumIE}\" />" +
                    "               <Style.Triggers>" +
                    "                   <DataTrigger Binding=\"{Binding NumIE}\" Value=\"-1\">" +
                    "                       <Setter Property=\"Text\" Value=\"\" />" +
                    "                   </DataTrigger>" +
                    "               </Style.Triggers>" +
                    "           </Style>" +
                    "       </TextBlock.Style>" +
                    "    </TextBlock>" +
                    "</DataTemplate>";

        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn() { CellTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(CellTemplate) as DataTemplate };
    }
}
```